# In mercurial, how to setup and use per-user platform-dependent hgrc?

Tags: unix, mercurial

System-level hgrc files (in `/etc/mercurial` and `<install-root>/etc/mercurial`) are obviously platform-dependent, but how I can use platform-dependent hgrc on a per user basis?

The use case is to override a system config on a specific platform. For example, we have hg on linux and solaris with different merge tools. How do I override just the solaris merge tool, when hgrc doesn't allow any control logic (like `if os.uname()[0] == 'SunOS'`)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. Keep a set of `.<platform>.hgrc` files with whatever you want to override in each one.
2. Set an environment variable in your `.bashrc`:

   ```
   export PLATFORM=`python -c 'import os; print os.uname()[0],'`
   ```
3. In your `~/.hgrc` file, use `%include` at the end to include the right file:

   ```
   %include ~/$PLATFORM.hgrc
   ```

Comment: `$PLATFORM` is exactly what I need. I should've seen it from man hgrc: "Environment variables and ~user constructs are expanded in file. This lets you do something like: `%include ~/.hgrc.d/$HOST.rc`
to include a different configuration file on each computer you use." Thank you, the elegant Mr. Losh!

Comment: Isn't there a built-in option to setup the settings for different remotes? This method works, but I don't like it. This comment is not meant to start a fight, I think this works a solution but I would prefer to have this setup controlled by the Mercurial configuration files and not have to add any environment variable. If you know a way, please let me know.