# Mercurial: remote operation with different environments (remotecmd .hgrc)

Tags: mercurial, remote-server, hgrc

There are two project in which I collaborate, they live in different servers, A and B.
While A has the `hg` program in `/opt/mercurial/bin/hg`, B has it in `/usr/local/bin/hg`.

When I want to pull/push changes to either remote, I have to manually modify `.hgrc`file in order for the option `remotecmd`to point to the right location of `hg`.

I would like to know if it is possible to setup different `remotecmd`paths for different remotes so that I don't have to manually change the path of the `hg`program everytime I need to do some remote operation.

I saw this question: [Setup platform-dependent hgrc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4607273/in-mercurial-how-to-setup-and-use-per-user-platform-dependent-hgrc) but it seemed to me that there should be a more native (something like a built-in setting) way to do this. So far I haven't been able to find it, so any help will be welcome :)

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ideally you just get the `hg` binary into your `$PATH` on both servers and you don't have to think about it anymore.  That can be done in the system's `/etc/profile` or in your `.ssh/enviironment` on that remote server.  Most people **never** even need to think about `remotecmd`.

If they're separate projects (or even separate clones locally of the same project) you can set the `remotecmd` in the `.hg/hgrc` file within each repository -- settings don't just have to be in your `~/hgrc` file.

Also be aware that `--remotecmd` is available as a command line option for push and pull, so you could use that and even combine it with something like:

```
[alias]
pusha = push --remotecmd /opt/mercurial/bin/hg
```

and then you can just do `hg pusha`

Really though, just try to get `hg` into your path like everyone else does.

Comment: The suggestion in the first paragraph assumes that one has administrator access to the server.  I have a shared server, where I can't edit `/etc/profile` and it's not set up to respect `.ssh/environment`.